# SSH Public Key Authentication denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machines

I am trying to connect to a virtual machine via SSH.

I can login to an account with a password.

I created another user without a password, generated a ssh key on my host machine (Windows), and placed the public key inside the user/.ssh/authorized_keys, and set the permission to read only, with full ownership of the user.

However, when I try to ssh, from localhost on the VM OR from my host machine, the public key is always denied. I have configured the ssh server to accept only public key authentication.

This is the error that I get when I run `ssh -vv user@localhost -i privatekey`

```
PS C:\Users\gicum\.ssh> ssh -vv mironica@192.168.230.129 -p 2222 -i mironica
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 192.168.230.129
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.230.129 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.230.129 [192.168.230.129] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file mironica.pub type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file mironica.pub-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/mironica type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/mironica-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.230.129:2222 as 'mironica'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:gS6dFKtHfhm8j4RkJ41ISAn0XS5KLrGlAD+QCHMp8qc
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '192.168.230.129' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: mironica.pub (00000266CA181500), explicit, agent
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/mironica (00000266CA181030), explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:JbiX5u8cO0CxDtwgv258/TLUWyG/xh4XwTvGIQjdXrc mironica.pub
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:JbiX5u8cO0CxDtwgv258/TLUWyG/xh4XwTvGIQjdXrc C:\\Users\\gicum/.ssh/mironica
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
mironica@192.168.230.129: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The issue is similar when trying via localhost as mentioned above.
I can't figure out what could possibly be my problem here?

**The public key**

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDPPRMQ3Z+aYhluLi0iY9atBjliwNCvZb3FjywsbiVDYotuWrO8Ee/dRrCVaNF9fRU44JdMm9rZ1FH6HRbLejQiUpATiOxUIno6kKfa8GZjFwrf0Q80H0G2n8zqkZMdP4DbDI1PMLpNT60n/LWv1FOgw7dr/TRlNCzb/J4socm1kXKDRcE5B4xkh8uCuK9QevwMcJ3iqkZ9v3bxBI/N+VyBPE3WfBwzNKX3xZPB9BQirRSRyAffh3DLaEik4tMtDTmYqbpsLXcHnG9rUh1vrCxoB56RtphMR3D3ORNl0XBy3E5mXEo5jqvRMMG7kRyVv9jSnDPM6UiO+sF2vawjRZzouXZHZKLOsOycMbx/lX/jB4TGcLRs+BiRyfMEYvrbr5SzhFPikyn15lFFQSVl+rTnoW3xg05CpEqVTwZqoWPfEUar1UzbRex7QJN9BKqCFeoBH/jTaUvw+8a3T+ELV4co+PI3J7+RhdOsiZGFxJ5D20+Ik2BbBw0qMsFnhmprX+ltDP6D3hXd5vCj3EqK6blgjfQofsHdZsLGem6lxYCoF41FmNLJIR0S7luz30ewUw+3Haiks1ti0Vmgle6RNLyrddRkwWrO0pkyRkDA1Q5BOO34EHvGUXb/FKGrMr0ngccTBINY2G3AMeHOzpCSO/9BnK+YrikLjEj86TxqIB9gEQ== gicum@bosslife
```

**/var/log/auth.log**

```
Sep 15 14:03:45 ubuntu sshd[9423]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Sep 15 14:03:45 ubuntu sshd[9423]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 15 14:03:45 ubuntu sshd[9423]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep 15 14:17:02 ubuntu CRON[11586]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 15 14:17:02 ubuntu CRON[11586]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 15 14:24:49 ubuntu sshd[11884]: Connection reset by authenticating user mironica 192.168.230.1 port 50138 [preauth]
Sep 15 14:25:16 ubuntu sshd[11904]: Connection reset by authenticating user mironica 192.168.230.1 port 50141 [preauth]
Sep 15 14:26:47 ubuntu sshd[11955]: Connection reset by authenticating user mironica 192.168.230.1 port 50173 [preauth]
Sep 15 14:27:01 ubuntu sshd[11965]: Connection reset by authenticating user mironica 192.168.230.1 port 50182 [preauth]
Sep 15 14:27:20 ubuntu sshd[11980]: Connection reset by authenticating user mironica 192.168.230.1 port 50194 [preauth]
Sep 15 14:42:48 ubuntu gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
```

Comment: I suggest you post your exact authorized_keys here.  It's just a public key so it's not really sensitive.  Also, what @MichaelHampton says - the server is the one looking at authorized_keys, and that's where you'll find the error message.  Check `/var/log/secure` and `/var/log/messages` if you don't know where the logging goes

Comment: With nothing logged on the server, it's most likely you are using the wrong key. Check it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem.

On the VM, I created the user, /home/user and stored the public key in ./ssh/authorized_keys.

I also made sure I set up the permissions correctly:

```
1. sudo chmod 700 /home/user
2. sudo chmod 400 authorized_keys
```

But, I never checked who had these rights, apparently, they were assigned to root.
So I did the following:

```
1. sudo chown user:user /home/user
2. sudo chown user:user authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set password for the user you want to use for passwordless connection, then you can set public key authentication. And if you are able to connect to remote machine you can run ssh in debug mode to find the problem.

in remote machine

```
#ddd is debug mode level.
$ stopsrc -s sshd

$ /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

then try to connect to remote machine from yours, when connection published the messages will be printed on your remote machine terminal that you started sshd.

Answer (score 0):

I created `.ssh` dir and `authorized_keys` file but forgot to `cd` into the dir, so `authorized_keys` file was outside of `.ssh`.